# Is there anyway to stop Viewing Recent projects in VS?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I don't want my recent projects to be viewed in the start page of Visual studio, I know how to delete them from the registry but i do not want to do this every time. Is there any option to stop this?

Comment: Do you still want the Start Page? Otherwise, just don't use the Start Page. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no. It is a 'feature' of the start page. The only quick option I can think of would be to turn off the Start Page (it is almost the first setting I change with a fresh install of VS).

...

If you wanted to be really tricky you could write a small start-up or shut-down macro that auto deletes those keys from the registry and (not sure if this would work and it is dangerous) change the permissions for the registry key where the recent projects are saved.

Comment: I disabled the start up page , i also read that it fasten up the opening of VS. Thank you :)

Comment: It is not going to solve your 'security' issues as the recent items are still visible from the File menu.

Comment: Maybe you can set the number of recent entries to show to 0 or -1? Or just go with the macro.

Comment: The minimum no. of allowed recent project is 1., but it's a good idea. Thank you :).

Comment: I don't know that is the risk  of doing that macro?

Comment: Re: The risk with the macro is just cautionary advice that I give to *anyone* that wanting to modify the registry; you can do it, however just be certain you know **what** you're doing.